# CMake way to generate multiple projects from common source tree

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-c++, cmake

My C++ project is very large and results in 5 different binaries to be generated. In VStudio for example, my single solution has 5 different "projects". In XCode for example, my single project has 5 different targets.

The code is organized in a very deep "src" folder with many many levels of nested sub folders. This src folder is common to all 5 binaries because there is heavy reuse of much of the source, but each binary requires some of the source but not all of it.

I'd like to know how to efficiently create a CMakeList.txt that can create what I need here.

Notes:

- Reorganizing the code into a different structure is not an option nor is making the code a bunch of static libraries.
- A CMakeList.txt for each subfolder is not an option. There's too many of them and maintenance would be a nightmare.
- A file(GLOB_RECURSE is not a great option either because it's going to pick up a ton of source files for each binary that are unnecessary to compile for that particular binary.
- Ideally, ONE XCode project (with 5 targets) or ONE VStudio Solution (with 5 projects) would be generated. I don't want 5 different projects to open.

I would be completely content with having to manually add/remove source files from a giant list somewhere...ideally in an external file that could be sucked up by CMake. E.g. SourceFilesForBinary1.txt, SourceFilesForBinary2.txt etc. but i'm not sure how to do that or if that's insane.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake has an include function. You can use that to implement your "giant manually managed list somewhere" solution.

You know that GLOB_RECURSE an be given a pattern, right, so it excludes uninteresting files? Even if not, everywhere you can use a GLOB_RECURSE you could also use an include and an evil manually-managed list.

I'm not sure why you don't want static libraries. Those are a good solution to this problem. For a large pile of shared code like this, if you compile it once into a relocatable static library and then link that with LTO into your various uses, you avoid recompiling the source many times. If your use is a shared library (so the static library approach would make all your unused symbols disappear), you can use the --whole-archive compiler switch to preserve them.

Comment: As a general note, it's quite unhelpful to ask a question with an associated list of unexplained "Don't solve it like this" clauses. If you explain why you rejected each of them, others might spot something you'd missed that makes them a solution to your problem!

Comment: I actually used include() as well as "target_sources" to achieve what I was hoping to. This lets me have a separate "mini-makefile" for each target to keep the target specific settings and sources out of the way of the bulk of the CMake logic.